# SQL Sentry has permission issue to gather SQL Server performance stats

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using the SQL Sentry tool to monitor my SQL Server 2008 instances to get performance report. I have created a user `sqlmonitor` in prod SQL Server (target) for monitoring purposes. I gave it the roles `sysadmin`, `serveradmin`.

I cannot login to the machine using windows authentication as we are different domain and don't want to touch the windows user configuration. SQL Sentry throws the errors shown below due to which it couldn't monitor the system performance. What permission do I need to provide to `sqlmonitor` to have permission to monitor?

> Errors: Initialization failed. Error: 30 initialization errors.
>
> Initialization Error:
>   Message: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
>   Access is denied
>   Message: WMI access was denied. Please ensure the SQL Sentry Monitoring Service user account has Windows Administrator privileges on the target server.
>
> Message: WMI access was denied. Please ensure the SQL Sentry Monitoring Service user account has Windows Administrator privileges on the target server.
>
> Message: WMI access was denied. Please ensure the SQL Sentry Monitoring Service user account has Windows Administrator privileges on the target server.
>
> Message: WMI access was denied. Please ensure the SQL Sentry Monitoring Service user account has Windows Administrator privileges on the target server.
>
> Message: WMI access was denied. Please ensure the SQL Sentry Monitoring Service user account has Windows Administrator privileges on the target server.
>
> Message: WMI access was denied. Please ensure the SQL Sentry Monitoring Service user account has Windows Administrator privileges on the target server.
>
> Message: WMI access was denied. Please ensure the SQL Sentry Monitoring Service user account has Windows Administrator privileges on the target server.
>
> Message: Error reading performance category Processor.
>   Message: Error reading performance category Memory.
>   Message: Error reading performance category Network Interface.
>   Message: Error reading performance category PhysicalDisk.
>   Message: Error reading performance category Process.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:Access Methods.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:Buffer Manager.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:Databases.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:General Statistics.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:Locks.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:Memory Manager.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:SQL Statistics.
>   Message: Error reading performance category System.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:Plan Cache.
>   Message: Error reading performance category Paging File.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:Buffer Node.
>   Message: Error reading performance category SQLServer:Database Mirroring.
>   Message: Error reading performance category Processor Information.

Comment: What user is running the SQL Sentry Service?  It looks like it needs to be an admin on your Prod SQL Server.

Comment: sqlmonitor user account. I already gave sysadmin, srvadmin role

Comment: No, the domain account running the service - this would be outside of SQL.

Comment: `sysadmin` is a SQL Server server-level role. In order to collect operating system-level performance and metadata from WMI, the monitoring service account needs privileges in Windows, not in SQL Server. Have you [contacted support](http://www.sqlsentry.com/#support)? Since you are going across domains I highly recommend you go that route and they can help you configure your environment properly.